# Deploy Angular2 using ember-cli

Tags: angular

I am trying to deploy my angular2 app in git hub.
Here is what i did step by step:

1- Create a new angular2 app using `ng new deploy`

2-create new repository
`git init` and `git remote add origin repo-uri`

3-`git add .` and `git commit -m "prepare for deploy"`

4-`ng github-pages:deploy`
Unfortunately, in this step i face with following message:

```
Running without elevated rights. Running Ember CLI "as Administrator" increases performance significantly.
See ember-cli.com/user-guide/#windows for details.

Built project successfully. Stored in "dist/".
Deployed! Visit [https://salman-.github.io/dep1/][1]
Github pages might take a few minutes to show the deployed site.
```

When i navigate to the [uri](https://salman-.github.io/dep1/) there is nothing there.

What is wrong with my deployment?

**Update:**
The first time I tried to push I faced with the following errors:

```
fs.js:60
      throw err;  // Forgot a callback but don't know where? Use NODE_DEBUG=fs
      ^

Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Salman\Desktop\Nuroscience\dep1\dist\vendor\reflect-metadata\temp'
    at Error (native)
```

So, I deleted the `dist` folder manually, and i push my code again, and this time it get pushed correctly.

[Here](https://github.com/salman-/deploy1) is the github code uri.

Comment: what's your github profile url?

Answer (score -1):

You have changed project name to `deploy1`

So Now your site is pointed to https://salman-.github.io/deploy1/

Comment: Yes, your are right. but it still does not load, because of some 404 errors. What do you think?

Comment: You did some mistake in your code.

You didn't give github profile url, I had to find it.  
You didn't commit any code into github, how do you expect me to provide solution?

Comment: I have updated my question, and added the url of repo.

Comment: You are using old version of angular-cli, update it to beta 16 and generate project again, it will work fine